# mongoose Collection.find(); return

Tags: express, mongoose

I use EXPRESS and MONGOOSE.
My code looks like this.

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){
   article.find({}, function(err, articles){
      if(err){
         console.log(err);
      }else{
         console.log(articles);

         res.render('index',{
            name:'home page',
            articles: articles        
         });
     }
 });
 });
```

What I get from db is an empty object ("**articles**").

Can not figure out why.

I do not think it's an asynchronous problem
Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Empty object (`{}`) or empty array (`[]`)?

Comment: You're right, my mistake
It's was an empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it!

change version of mongoose to @4.10.8
it work correct.
still not fully understand what was wrong. i'll upda